# Lua corona SDk convert correct answer to percentage % using if else

Tags: math, lua, coronasdk

I am trying to figure out a simple true false quiz app using corona SDK. Now I can count correct answer using  text= myData.ScoreCount
Please the correct:

```
 local textoPontuacao = {
       text= myData.ScoreCount,-- correct score is counting
         x = ganhou.x + 310,
         y = ganhou.y - 47,
         width = 700,
         font = native.systemFontBold,
         fontSize = 36,
        }
        local t=50 -- total questions
        local c=textoPontuacao -- textoPontuacao counts correct answer
        local pc=(c/t)*100
        local r

       if pc >=60 and pc<70 then
       r = "Not Bad!"
       elseif pc >=70 and pc<80 then
       r = "Good Match!"
       elseif pc >=80 and pc<95 then
       r = "Very Good Match!"
       elseif pc >=95 and pc<101 then
       r = "Excellent!"
       else
          r = "You have to Think"
        end

        local textoPon = display.newText( r )-- normally if i use textoPontuacao instead of r, it prints correct Answer.
       textoPon:setFillColor( 1,1,1 )
       sceneGroup:insert(textoPon)
```

now i want to print String value from if else statement instead of correct answer. if i use textoPontuacao for print, then it display correct answer. Someone help to solve this issue will greatly appreciated. And I need to convert correct answers to percentage % too, but not clear how? I am new to lua and corona SDK , just trying to customizing a simple game.

Comment: What isn't working here exactly? You seem to be dividing a table by a number. Is that giving you an error?

Comment: hi, Thanks, I get an error, attempt to perform arithmatic in local 'c'( a table value), is it table--------local textoPontuacao = {
       text= myData.ScoreCount,-- correct score is counting
         x = ganhou.x + 310,
         y = ganhou.y - 47,
         width = 700,
         font = native.systemFontBold,
         fontSize = 36,
        }

Comment: Yeah, that would be because you are trying to divide a table by a number. Did you mean `local c = t.text` to get the count there?

Comment: yes, I tried now, and it says an error, attempt to index a local 't'(a number value)

Comment: Sorry, I meant `local c = textoPontuacao.text` or `local c = myData.ScoreCount` or just `local pc = (myData.ScoreCount / t) * 100`.

Comment: it says bad argument, number expected, no value for above there's

Comment: `Bad argument` is about a call to a function not that math line. Where is that error coming from? Does it say?

Comment: when it is time to display result of correct score, it says error

Comment: So the `display.newText` call is throwing the error? Or some other call/code?

Comment: yes, display.newText is showing erorr,

Comment: `display.newText` shouldn't require a number (it seems to take a string) are you sure that's the problem?

Comment: yes, now i want to display string r, so how can i rewrite  display.newtext for r variable

Comment: `display.newText(r)` should work just fine I think. I don't see, offhand, why it wouldn't (but I also don't really know Corona at all). I'd make sure that's the line that is actually failing for you.

Comment: I understand, but many many thanks for your support, though we are not success yet

Answer (score 0):

though finally i solved the issue, but i want to thank Mr. Etan Reisner , He helps me much. I am grateful to HIM. Now I am telling the issue, we used  local textoPon = display.newText(r) before and now I have used  local textoPon = display.newText(r,195,150, "Arial", 35) and it is solved.